# Android Variable in XML file

Tags: android, seekbar

How do I read in a variable to an XML file. This is a seekbar I have

```
<SeekBar
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="10px"
   android:id="@+id/seekbar"
   android:max="100"
   android:progress="50"
   />
```

I want to change the android:max to a variable as it will change. How is this done? Thanks

Comment: As msarchet points out, the correct way to mark a problem as solved is to click the checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. That will tell everyone that your problem is solved, and give msarchet credit for being the first person to post a correct solution for you (even if you figured it out yourself, it's still nice to give him credit for his help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create an instance of the `SeekBar` by it's id `seekbar`

`Seekbar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);`

And then you will set the value that you want to set

`seekbar.max = yourNewValue;`

Comment: Ya sorry that was such a stupid question. I figured it out just after posting. Thanks for your help though. Too hungover for this :)

Thanks

Comment: @Owen O'Brien no problem since I see you are new here the correct thing to do is select my answer as the correct one

Comment: Will do. It says I need to wait a few minutes though. Thanks again for fast reply